# What is the most efficient way to sum a fractional part of a double and increment when it "overflows"?

Tags: c++, floating-accuracy

To make a long story short, I have a piece of code, well over a decade old, that is in use both by us and by outside customers. We have a "shift" number by which we move a shifting window. It was designed as an integer because, well, we're going over distinct positions in the data, so there was no conception of a fractional move. Now, they'd like to be able to have a non-integer shift number. Not interpolation, but simply having the program do an integer shift, but have it shift by a little more when we pass that boundary.

An example may make more sense. Let's say that we have a shift of 10. The positions will go as follows:
0, 10, 20, 30, 40, etc

Now, instead, we want to be able to set a shift of 10.4. Thus, we want the shift to work as follows:
0, 10, 20, **31**, 41, etc

A shift of 10.5 would instead come out as 0, 10, 21, 31, 42, and so on.

Basically, we sum up that fractional bit and when it crosses the decimal point, we just shift by one more. Of course, as often happens with floating point operations, we run into potential issues of accuracy, but we also want to keep the speed up. One naive approaches are to either separate that fractional bit out at the start and keep summing it up, checking its value and decrementing it when it hits 1.0. This has the advantage of following how I tend to think of the operation, but it involves a conditional check every iteration and there's the usual potential for accumulative errors.

I could also see pre-calculating how many times we can add that fractional bit before we have to check to see if it exceeds 1.0 (so if our fractional bit is 0.5, we know that we only need to check every other time. Or if it's 0.3, we know that we only have to check every four or so).

The usual approach to handling repeated summing is, of course, to replace it with a multiplication, but here, we don't care so much about the actual sum as we do predicting which frames we need to "shift one more" on to make things match up at the end.

The typical task we have involves this class operating on a relatively small combination of factors, for example iterating with a shift of 96.46875 for less than 3000 times. However, there's no guarantee that this constraint will remain valid, so I've been told to account for the possibility that someone will shift the window ten million times and we'll still want to know how far to shift.

Any advice?

Comment: Are the shifts additive or multiplicative?

Comment: I believe they are additive. We're at position 0, then 10, then 21, and so on, up to an upper limit (our window size) whereupon we start on the other side.

Comment: @SeanDuggan: do you need to generate the full list of windows, or just produce the result of shifting N times ?

Comment: @MatthieuM.
Actually, due to how the base class is written, I need to provide the current value for a given frame. My current method, the naive approach I mentioned above, overrides the nextFrame method to first reduce the value below 1.0 if it's met or exceeded that, then adds the fractional value. Another function, getShift, returns the current shift using ''return intShift_ + (fractionalShift_ >= 1.0 ? 1 : 0);''.

Unfortunately, that means the the multiplicative method is not necessarily going to work very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider setting `shift` to the double nearest the desired value and increasing it slightly (just once) with:

```
shift = nexttoward(shift, INFINITY); // Ensure shift is above the threshold.
```

Then, to calculate the current position, use:

```
result = floor(step * shift);
```

This may produce a value too large when the product of `step` and the error in `shift` nears one. (There may also be a slight rounding error in the multiplication itself.) However, that will not occur for many steps, as shown below.

The error in `shift` is at most 1.5 ULP (.5 ULP from the initial conversion from decimal and 1 from `nexttoward`). If `shift` is less than 1024, an ULP is less than 2<sup>10–52</sup>. If `step` is at most 10,000,000, then the error is less than 10,000,000 • 1.5 • 2<sup>10–52</sup>, which is approximately 3.41•10<sup>–6</sup>. So it remains a long way from the magnitude necessary to produce an incorrect result.

If you calculate the result cumulatively by adding `shift` each time, instead of by a fresh multiplication, then there may be additional errors. These likely remain too small to cause an error, but they should be evaluated.

If you reach the limits described above, there are ways to mitigate the errors further.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the floor function. Without seeing what code you've got, here's a guess at what would work

```
    for (int i=0; i < 3000; i++)
    {
        cout << static_cast<int>(floor(i*shift)) << '\n';
    }
```

One could argue against the efficiency of this approach, but if you are talking less than 3000 iterations, you are fine.

Comment: Consider the 100th position when the desired shift is 1.13. The expression `floor(100*1.13)` evaluates to 112, but 113 is desired. This occurs because the result of converting “1.13” to double is a value slightly smaller than 1.13 (using IEEE-754 64-bit binary floating-point and round-to-nearest).

Comment: Certainly rounding errors can occur. The assumption is that shift is already a double, so that error already exists and is not introduced by the above code.